# Redirect API access to login page and back to API - Preserve data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, vaadin-flow

I've got a web application which got a secured UI layer over a login form (e.g. /ui). Additionally there is a API layer (e.g. /api) for communication with a client which does not need a UI.

Now if the client starts up, it send a POST Request with the following example data:

```
{
   "ipv4" : "192.168.0.100",
   "name" : "unknown"
}
```

The server gets this request and see that there is an additional attribute called "login" missing (which is a Login ID, e.g. a combination of username + password) and should redirect the user to the login page, fill in the ID and afterwards fullfill the POST request with the complete request body like and process this request:

```
{
   "ipv4" : "192.168.0.100",
   "name" : "unknown",
   "login" : "password12345"
}
```

I am using Vaadin with Spring Boot.

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE:**
My use case is as follows: There is a UI which show devices connected to a specific "login". If a user starts a new "device", the device is not linked to a "login" unless he logs in with his specific "login".

The process is as follows:

```
User --> Starts Device --> Device not connected to "login" --> User should enter his "login" --> Server notifies device, that it is now connected to an "login".
```

Maybe there is a better way to achieve this, that I explained it.